# Remove first place comma and space between two texts and the last comma or space

Tags: r

I have joined multiple columns in from a data frame into a single column. Now because of the formatting I am getting some issues. I want to remove comma if it at the first place and last place comma.Also I want to delete the space coming in between the texts. 
eq: if the combines string :

, this is test, dd,pqr, then this should be converted to this is test,dd,prq

```
df <- as.data.frame(rbind(c('11061002','11862192','11083069'),
                          c(" ",'1234567','452589'),
                          c("fs","  ","dd","  ")))

df$f1 <-paste0(df$V1,
               ',',
               "  ",
               df$V2,
               ',',
               "  ",
               df$V3,',',df$V4)   

df_1 <- as.data.frame(df[,c(5)])
names(df_1)[1] <-"f1"
```

expected output is :

```
11061002,11862192,11083069,11061002 (No spaces)  
1234567,452589  
fs,dd
```

Regards, 
R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using double `gsub` :

```
gsub(',{2,}', ',', gsub('^,|,$| ', '', trimws(df_1$f1)))
#[1] "11061002,11862192,11083069,11061002" "1234567,452589"  "fs,dd"
```

`,{2,}` - Replaces more than 2+ consecutive commas with one comma.

`^,` - removes commas at start.

`,$` - removes commas at end.

and remove whitespaces from the string.

Comment: just a variant that works too: `apply(df, 1, function(x) gsub(",,", ",", gsub("^,|,$", "", paste0(trimws(x), collapse=","))))`

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have double space in third row. One way to approach this is to use `apply` with margin `1` to do a rowwise operation; in your case, `paste`, i.e.

```
apply(df, 1, function(i)paste(i[!i %in% c(' ', '  ')], collapse = ','))
#[1] "11061002,11862192,11083069" "1234567,452589"             "fs,dd"
```